# Get PC TimeZone on C#

Tags: c#, timezone-offset

Im currently developing on asp - c# as a backend code. I want to get the current timezone that was set on the PC.

The below code are still identifying what is the correct timezone of my current area (+8GMT) even though I already changed my PC timezone settings into another timezone.

What I want is to get the timezone offset specified on the PC date settings. Can anyone help me on this. Below is my code so far.

```
public TimeSpan currentOffset;
public DateTime utc;
public DateTime local;

this.utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.Utc.Id);
this.local = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id);
this.currentOffset = this.local.Subtract(this.utc);
```

Comment: How could I know the specified timezone offset on my PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to David Haney's answer.

[TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is caching data after first call so any changes in PC settings will not affect your application if it is already running.
You should call [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.clearcacheddata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
```

to refresh this cache.
So this one will work in your case:

```
 TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
 var offsetTimespan = DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset;
 var offsetInHours = offsetTimespan.TotalHours;
```

Comment: You did it man!! It works!! TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData() is a tweak. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're making your life harder than it needs to be. :)

Use `DateTimeOffset`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
```

This will include the time zone offset information as well.